# I'm having a hard time launching my IntellijIDEA 2019.2

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I tried running the idea batch file from the bin folder and it worked.  but i wouldn't like to have to open through the batch file.

[image]

Comment: Did you set JAVA_HOME as your message suggests?

Comment: Yes. just as it should be done

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Please ensure that `JAVA_HOME` variable is defined in `Environment Variables`. Seems like currently your `JAVA_HOME` points to IntelliJ IDEA directory, but it should point at Java installation directory.

For example, my `JAVA_HOME` is defined as: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221`

Comment: My JAVA_HOME variable is exactly as you specified but it's still not working

Comment: That's strange...

Try to log out/log in, it sometimes helps with environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have(or download) a 64-bit version of the JDK.

Then follow this tutorial to set up the JAVA_HOME variable:

https://www.google.com/amp/s/javatutorial.net/set-java-home-windows-10/amp

Comment: Following the tutorial you recommended, i tested my JAVA_HOME path and version through the command prompt (cmd) and it worked well.  But the IntellijIDEA keeps showing the error message

Comment: You made sure you're using a 64-bit version of the JDK